# Show wordpress last comments in template

Tags: wordpress

i want show my 2 last comments in wordpress

my template :

```html
<div class=avatar><---user-photo---></div>
<div class=name><---user-name-and-link---></div>
<div class=content><---comment-content---></div>
```

what code must put in <---> fields?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="contentbox paddindbox">
  <section class="wrapper group">
    <aside class="textbox aligncenter">
      <h2>باور نمیکنید؟ نگاهی به نظرات کاربران بیندازید ...</h2>
      <div id=testimonial_slider class="testimonial_slider owl-carousel">
        <div class=testimonial_box>
          <?php $args = array(    
              'status' => 'approve',  
              'number' => '2', 
              'post_id' => 2, // use post_id, not post_ID 
          );
          $comments = get_comments($args);
          foreach($comments as $comment) :
              $user_email = $comment->comment_author_email;
              $avatar = get_avatar( $user_email, 32 ); 
          ?>
          <div class=testimonial_lt>
            <aside class=client_commentBox>
              <figure class=image_holder><?php echo $avatar; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp</figure>

              <p><?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?></p>
            </aside>
            <h5><?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?></h5>
          </div>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
```